# Setting up server code from localhost to server

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, sockets

I've been trying to get some code runing.

The code can be found at the next link [code link](https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM)

As you can see it got a Client and a Server Code, this code is an android instant messenger based on socket communication.

The Server Code is containing three files - one sql file and two php files.

The thing is that when i tested the code using XAMPP as a localhost all worked fine.

The problems began when i tried to move it to a server.

What i have done is simple - i've open an account at serversfree.com. Then there i went to the MySQL database and created a database name: and username. After that i uploaded the sql file.

Then i went to the file manager option - and upload to it the index.php and the mysql.class.php. And also i've edit at the index.php file the four relevant lines -

```
$dbHost = "";
$dbUsername = "DBUSERNAME";
$dbPassword = "DBPASSWORD";
$dbName = "DBNAME";
```

Of course the input for each line is not the same as shown here.

The problem is, for example, when a user is trying to sign up - when i tried it at a localhost all went fine, but with the server - at the client side it tells the user that something went wrong and the signing up failed - But when i having a look at the mySQL table i can see that the user info sure got into the table, and even i can log in with that user info.

Another problem i'm having is when a user tries to add up another user to his contact list - is sure seem not to work. 
Even when im going to the mySQL table and changing the value from 0 to 1 - as if to say that friend request is approved - still the user name is not showing up at the friends list. That thing sure worked at the localhost scenario.

Well i hope that someone here could help me to figure out what making this problem.

Here's the android's logcat when i press on sign up -

```
    03-05 15:48:20.834: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(2346): SIOP:: AP = 300, Prev AP = 300, Duration = 10002
03-05 15:48:21.214: I/InputReader(2346): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.13493 ] when=137349122712000
03-05 15:48:21.214: I/InputDispatcher(2346): Delivering touch to: action: 0x0
03-05 15:48:21.269: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(31809): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
03-05 15:48:21.284: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(31809): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:2
03-05 15:48:21.359: I/InputReader(2346): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=137349265664000
03-05 15:48:21.359: I/InputDispatcher(2346): Delivering touch to: action: 0x1
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346): Writing exception to parcel
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-05 15:48:21.359: E/DatabaseUtils(2346):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-05 15:48:21.359: W/ActivityManager(2346): Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
03-05 15:48:21.379: V/WindowManager(2346): Window{42eec348 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
03-05 15:48:21.399: I/SurfaceFlinger(1935): id=5600 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, Uoast
03-05 15:48:21.399: V/WindowManager(2346): Window{42eec348 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
03-05 15:48:21.419: D/PowerManagerService(2346): [api] acquire WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=2346
03-05 15:48:22.274: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(31809): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
03-05 15:48:22.284: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(31809): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:2
03-05 15:48:22.879: D/SensorService(2346):   1.9 4.0 8.4
03-05 15:48:23.284: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(31809): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
03-05 15:48:23.299: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(31809): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:2
03-05 15:48:23.329: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(2346): SIOP:: AP = 300 (read only)
03-05 15:48:23.554: D/dalvikvm(2346): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1476K, 18% free 47668K/57704K, paused 10ms+13ms, total 227ms
03-05 15:48:24.294: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(31809): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
03-05 15:48:24.304: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(31809): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:2
03-05 15:48:25.294: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(31809): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
03-05 15:48:25.299: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(31809): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:2
03-05 15:48:25.419: I/SurfaceFlinger(1935): id=5600 Removed Uoast (5/5)
03-05 15:48:25.419: I/SurfaceFlinger(1935): id=5600 Removed Uoast (-2/5)
03-05 15:48:25.424: D/PowerManagerService(2346): [api] [s] userActivity : event: 0 flags: 0 (uid: 1000 pid: 2346)
03-05 15:48:25.429: D/PowerManagerService(2346): [api] release WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=2346 (0x0)
03-05 15:48:25.429: D/PowerManagerService(2346): [api] applyWakeLockFlagsOnReleaseLocked : userActivityNoUpdateLocked is called : SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=2346, ws=WorkSource{10161}) (elapsedTime=4012)
```

Here's the code for each one of the php file-

index.php - code:

```
    <?php
/****************************************
*       Server of Android IM Application
*               
*       Supported actions: 
*           1.  authenticateUser
*               if user is authentiated return friend list
*           
*           2.  signUpUser
*       
*           3.  addNewFriend
*       
*           4.  responseOfFriendReqs
*
*           5.  testWebAPI
*************************************/


//TODO:  show error off

require_once("mysql.class.php");

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "DBUSERNAME";
$dbPassword = "DBPASSWORD";
$dbName = "DBNAME";


$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

// if operation is failed by unknown reason
define("FAILED", 0);

define("SUCCESSFUL", 1);
// when  signing up, if username is already taken, return this error
define("SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED", 2);  
// when add new friend request, if friend is not found, return this error 
define("ADD_NEW_USERNAME_NOT_FOUND", 2);

// TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS: if last authentication time of user is older 
// than NOW - TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS, then user is considered offline
define("TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS", 60);

define("USER_APPROVED", 1);
define("USER_UNAPPROVED", 0);


$username = (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && count($_REQUEST['username']) > 0) 
                            ? $_REQUEST['username'] 
                            : NULL;
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
$port = isset($_REQUEST['port']) ? $_REQUEST['port'] : NULL;

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
if ($action == "testWebAPI")
{
    if ($db->testconnection()){
    echo SUCCESSFUL;
    exit;
    }else{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
    }
}

if ($username == NULL || $password == NULL)  
{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
}

$out = NULL;

error_log($action."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
switch($action) 
{

    case "authenticateUser":


        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {                   

            // providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
            // providerId is the Id of making first friend request
            // requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId

            // fetching friends, 
            // left join exp<b></b>ression is a bit different, 
            //      it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself

            $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                        f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                            from friends f
                            left join users u on 
                                        u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                            where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                         f.requestId = ".$userId." ";

            //$sqlmessage = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username from messages m \n"
    . "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";


            if ($result = $db->query($sql))         
            {
                    $out .= "<data>"; 
                    $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
                    while ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                    {
                        $status = "offline";
                        if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                        {
                            $status = "unApproved";
                        }
                        else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                        {
                            $status = "online";

                        }
                        $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";

                                                // to increase security, we need to change userKey periodically and pay more attention
                                                // receiving message and sending message 

                    }
                        if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                            {
                            while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                                {
                                $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                                $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                                $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                                }
                            }
                    $out .= "</data>";
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
                // exit application if not authenticated user
                $out = FAILED;
        }



    break;

    case "signUpUser":
        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
             $email = $_REQUEST['email'];       

             $sql = "select Id from  users 
                            where username = '".$username."' limit 1";



             if ($result = $db->query($sql))
             {
                    if ($db->numRows($result) == 0) 
                    {
                            $sql = "insert into users(username, password, email)
                                values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ";                          

                                error_log("$sql", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql))   
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out = SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED;
                    }
             }                      
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "sendMessage":
    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {   
        if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
        {
             $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
             $message = $_REQUEST['message'];   

             $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";



                    if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                    {
                        while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                        {
                            $uto = $rowto->Id;
                        }
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";                       

                                error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                       
                        $resultto = NULL;
                    }   

        $sqlto = NULL;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "addNewFriend":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
            {               
                 $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];

                 $sql = "select Id from users 
                                 where username='".$friendUserName."' 
                                 limit 1";
                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                             $requestId = $row->Id;

                             if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {
                                     $sql = "insert into friends(providerId, requestId, status)
                                         values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".USER_UNAPPROVED.")";

                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;  // user add itself as a friend
                            }                                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }                               
                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }
            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "responseOfFriendReqs":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {
            $sqlApprove = NULL;
            $sqlDiscard = NULL;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['approvedFriends']))
            {
                  $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['approvedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }               

                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlApprove = "update friends set status = ".USER_APPROVED."
                                    where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                ";      
                  }

            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['discardedFriends']))
            {
                    $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['discardedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }                   
                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlDiscard = "delete from friends 
                                        where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                    providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                            ";
                  }                     
            }
            if (  ($sqlApprove != NULL ? $db->query($sqlApprove) : true) &&
                        ($sqlDiscard != NULL ? $db->query($sqlDiscard) : true) 
               )
            {
                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }
    break;

    default:
        $out = FAILED;      
        break;  
}

echo $out;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)
{

    $sql22 = "select * from users 
                    where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' 
                    limit 1";

    $out = NULL;
    if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
    {
        if ($row22 = $db->fetchObject($result22))
        {
                $out = $row22->Id;

                $sql22 = "update users set authenticationTime = NOW(), 
                                                                 IP = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' ,
                                                                 port = 15145 
                                where Id = ".$row22->Id."
                                limit 1";

                $db->query($sql22);             


        }       
    }

    return $out;
}

?>
```

mysql.class.php - code:

```
    <?php


class MySQL
{   
    private $dbLink;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUsername;
        private $dbPassword;
    private $dbName;
    public  $queryCount;

    function MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
    {
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;    
        $this->queryCount = 0;      
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }
    //connect to database
    private function connect() {    
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }   
    /*****************************
     * Method to close connection *
     *****************************/
    function close()
    {
        @mysql_close($this->dbLink);
    }
    /*******************************************
     * Checks for MySQL Errors
     * If error exists show it and return false
     * else return true  
     *******************************************/
    function ShowError()
    {
        $error = mysql_error();
        //echo $error;      
    }   
    /****************************
     * Method to run SQL queries
     ****************************/
    function  query($sql)
    {   
        if (!$this->dbLink) 
            $this->connect();

        if (! $result = mysql_query($sql,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();         
            return false;
        }
        $this->queryCount++;    
        return $result;
    }
    /************************
    * Method to fetch values*
    *************************/
    function fetchObject($result)
    {
        if (!$Object=mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $Object;
        }
    }
    /*************************
    * Method to number of rows
    **************************/
    function numRows($result)
    {
        if (false === ($num = mysql_num_rows($result))) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return -1;
        }
        return $num;        
    }
    /*******************************
     * Method to safely escape strings
     *********************************/
    function escapeString($string)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            return $string;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
            return $string;
        }
    }

    function free($result)
    {
        if (mysql_free_result($result)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }

    function lastInsertId()
    {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->dbLink);
    }

    function getUniqueField($sql)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($this->query($sql));

        return $row[0];
    }
    function testconnection() { 
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }       
}
```

Comment: "something went wrong and the signing up failed " - what exactly went wrong? What error message? Where?

Comment: I've added the android's logcat when i pressed on sign up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found out the problem seems like free hosting sites like - serversfree.com or 000webhost.com are adding to the code an analytics code.

So to overcome this - the solution for 000webhost, is as follows -

At the file manager, at [public_html] you need to create a file called [.htaccess]
and inside it you need to type -

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
php_value auto_append_file none
</FilesMatch>
```

This will prevent all .php files from been appended with the analytics code. Just replace [php] with any file extension where you want the analytics code removed.

and to prevent from your domain to get cancelled, don't disable your analytics code by going to the next link - http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php

EDIT - 
This also works with
serversfree.com